# Task Module - Failed to load Webview error when trying to open web app in mobile device Teams app

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

We are trying to open the web app in Teams chat bot using [**Task Module**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/invoking-task-modules) when user clicks on the adaptive card button.
The same is working fine in web browser and desktop teams app but not working when trying to open the task module in mobile device teams app. Getting the error displayed in the screenshot.
[Error in Android mobile teams app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFHnU.jpg)

Using *Bot card button* approach to invoke task module.

Domain is already present in the uploaded manifest validDomains list.

We have found the below link but didn't get success.
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/2665

Comment: Could you please confirm if you are facing this issue in Android or iOS? We checked in iOS with this sample https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-task-module/nodejs. We see that clicking on Adaptive card button does nothing in iOS - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg4GX.png

Comment: We have tested in Android multiple devices but not working showing the same error.

Comment: We will check once again internally and get back to you.

Comment: Hello @Asif - Please try to setup this sample code and check it once: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-task-module/nodejs

Answer (score 3):

We have tried to repo the issue, but it is working fine.
We have tested in below devices:

Android version- 14

[image]

iOS version 17.2.1

[image]

Please try to update your device, Microsoft team's client and try it once again.